# Secure Web Site with Non-Secure Mapbox Overlays

Tags: arcgis-server, wms, mapbox

We host a site that uses Mapbox.  We're testing running it as a secure(https) site and are getting errors within Chrome that it can't access non-secure data when coming from a secure site.  We are attempting to retrieve data from WMS and ArcGIS servers from our customers that are not secure and we have no control over.  What is the best method for retrieving the data from a secure site?

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps it is a setting under Chrome's hood?

[Google Chrome's team released a statement asking](https://www.chromium.org/Home/chromium-security/marking-http-as-non-secure) for http sites to be marked as non-secure with a large X on the lock symbol but they wrote that it would not break functionality.

Answer (score 0):

Your administrator might try unchecking the https requirement option.  Seems like this setting would be better if Esri made it at the app level, instead of for the entire Portal.

[image]

Comment: This has nothing to do with how ArcGIS is set up.  We are trying to run our site that we developed as https.  Our customers have WMS and ArcGIS servers that are not secure(http).  Chrome(and I'm assuming other browsers) is blocking requests to those map servers because it does not allow communication to a non-secure url from a secure site.

Comment: Ah, ok.  The question reads "Secure Web Site with Non-Secure Mapbox Overlays" ... maybe more appropriately "Secure Mapbox Web Site with Non-Secure map service Overlays".